# Wrong answer for question 10 of Project Euler

Tags: java, sum, primes

I was trying to solve question 10 of Project Euler, which is asking for the sum of all primes below two million ([reference](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10)). The answer I got is `143042032116`, but the actual answer is `142913828922`. What is wrong with the code?

```
package projectEuler;

public class Euler10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // sum of prime numbers below 2million
        long sum=0;

        int maxValue=2*1000*1000;
        for(int i=0;i<maxValue;i++) {
            boolean isPrime=true;   

            for(int j=2;j*j<i;j++) {
                if(i%j==0) {
                    isPrime=false;
                }
            }
            if(i<2) {
                isPrime=false;
            }
            if(isPrime==true) {
                sum+=i;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(sum);        
    }      
}
```

Comment: Why did you use ``2 * 1000 * 1000`` rather than 2_000_000?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in the condition of the nested loop which should be `j * j <= i` to exclude squares of odd numbers.

Also the nested loop should be optimized to complete as soon as non-prime number is detected.

The updated code is as follows:

```java
long sum = 0L;
    
int maxValue = 2_000_000;
for (int i=0; i < maxValue; i++) {
    
    boolean isPrime = true;   
    
    for(int j = 2; isPrime && j*j <= i; j++) {
        if(i % j == 0) {
            isPrime=false;
        }
    }
    if(i < 2) {
        isPrime = false;
    }
    if(isPrime) {
        sum += i;
    }
}
    
System.out.println(sum);
```

It produces correct response:

```
142913828922
```

---

If even numbers are not included in the loop, the sum of remaining odd primes can be counted faster:

```java
long sum = 2L; // add 2, as all the following even numbers are ignored
    
int maxValue = 2_000_000;
for (int i = 3; i < maxValue; i += 2) {
    
    boolean isPrime = true;   
    
    for(int j = 3; isPrime && j*j <= i; j += 2) {
        if(i % j == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }
    if(isPrime) {
        sum += i;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please say me how adding "isPrime" in the second loop makes the code more optimized ???.

Comment: Checking for `isPrime` allows to complete the loop as soon as any divisor `j` is found for `i` without extra iterations.